# How would normal colors be affected if a planet's atmosphere was green?

Tags: science-based, planets, science-fiction, atmosphere

Good day everyone.

I've recently finally gotten around to writing a sci fi novel but need help on some of the science of a few concepts I would like to incorporate in the novel.  I'll start with the first idea / question.

I'm looking to have a planet that has a green sky (Emerald like) but on the surface, I'm hoping to not have to worry about accounting for it relating to the descriptions of normal color.  From a science point of view...probably not possible.  But i would like to know -

1) Is there a why to have a green sky without affecting normal color descriptions on the planet's surface?

2) If not, how would the colors be affected? (Would only blue colors be affected?)

The viewpoint would be from pilot approaching the planet for the first time. He will eventually crash on the planet where the civilization is not a space faring one.  So I guess the questions would be from the perspective of:

A) the pilot and
B) the people on the planet

Appreciate any feedback on this. Thanks.

Cheers, 
Primordial

Comment: Welcome! Can you edit the question to elaborate on who the observers are, and how they got there? Humans that evolved under green skies may see objects differently from humans who landed there from Earth - and if your observers are aliens, it's a whole different story. I think right now, the answer is: "it depends on who's seeing."

Comment: I wonder if by "green atmosphere", you might actually just mean "the sky is green instead of blue"

Comment: Yeah...thanks...was thinking more of a green sky but the same type of atmosphere as  Earth.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Next time you may want to wait a bit longer before accepting an answer, there are many international readers having severe "jet lag" but might have the answer you are looking for. ;D

Comment: LOL good point...I'm still open to other ideas but I'm new to this and liked the concept :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your green atmosphere is caused by floating colonial algae.**

**[image: algae]**

https://blog.nationalgeographic.org/2014/07/09/transgender-algae-show-how-males-and-females-came-to-be/

Your aerial algae generate hydrogen inside themselves via hydrolysis of water.  They generate enough to float their svelte selves and their nitrogen fixing commensals up above the hullabaloo, up where there is sun and clouds and not much else except the occasional sky whale.

There are so many of them that the sky has a greenish cast, some days more than others.  On dry days they may come low, producing a green fog over the land, with some unfortunate floaties coming to rest on objects below.

These floating plants soak up a lot of light, but by no means all.  It is like walking in a forest on a sunny day.  The green leaves soak up a lot of light, but you can still tell your companion has red hair and a yellow shirt.

Comment: Thanks so much Willk.  This does appear exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It all depends on how much of the spectrum and intensity those plants "soak". If the competition for the light is fierce, they will get to absorb everything they can. [Here's an example](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRbAZ_JZMrqaxESZJ0eSjXptzQp1MPmz1wqoY1UfHa8oQB9l-oh) of how the plants look like when illuminated only with the spectrum they absorb and with an intensity they can cope "soaking" - note their mostly gray appearance of the shadows.

Answer (score 4):

**It would probably be monochromatic depending on density.**

The atmosphere of the Earth (and most planets whose surface we can see for that matter) is clear, or transparent within the range of visible light at least. For that reason, it doesn't have a material effect on the colours we are able to see. A green atmosphere on the other hand means that it's absorbing all colours OTHER than green, which it is either letting through or reflecting.

The point being that a planet with a green atmosphere is going to have a surface that looks green to a person with eyes that work in the same range as that which makes the atmosphere itself look green.

In practical terms, that makes it monochromatic, with several different versions of black like pure red, pure blue, etc. The trouble comes when you make the atmosphere quite dense, as this could actually limit the amount of green light getting through to the ground as well, especially if the gas in the atmosphere tends to reflect light - a highly dense gas cloud just might not let enough light through for you to see well in such a case. This is highly unlikely in all but rare circumstances as light blocking is more likely to be caused by contamination like dust particles, but then your atmosphere shouldn't be green either, so anything is possible. The point being, that if your atmosphere is dense enough, then your surface colours are going to go from green, to dark green, to black at differing levels of density and contamination.

Answer (score 2):

A human landing there would rapidly adjust to the spectral intensity available.  It would be similar to what we perceive near sunset.  If you take a photo (with film; modern solid-state cameras tend to auto-correct shading) of anything, the picture will come out with a strong orange-red cast, but while you were sitting there, things looked just about right.  There's a ton of neurologic interpretation of the retinal signals that goes on.

BTW,  you might be able to posit an atmosphere with either larger particles than Earth's (thus causing scattering into the green, not just the blue) or with high concentration of red-yellow absorbing gaseous atoms.  No need for huge particles like algae.